# Angular 5 - google is not defined (Google Maps)

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript, google-maps-api-3, npm

I want to use google maps on my Angular 5 app, but I encourtered some problem.

When view is loading I receive error in js console:

```
LoginComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined 
at LoginComponent.ngAfterViewInit (login.component.ts:15) 
at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:12428)..
```

My component:

```
  import {AfterViewInit, Component} from '@angular/core';
    declare let google: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements AfterViewInit {

       ngAfterViewInit(): void {
          let origin = new google.maps.LatLng(4.0, 2.0 );
          let destination = new google.maps.LatLng(1.0, 1.5);
       }

       constructor() {}
    }
```

app.module.ts

```
import {AgmCoreModule} from '@agm/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'KEY'
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I'm using AgmCoreModule installed by npm:

```
npm install @agm/core --save
```

I tried also importing LatLang class this way:

```
import LatLng = google.maps.LatLng;
```

And use script in my index.html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&libraries=places" async defer></script>
```

But all the time I received same issues.
Am I missing something?

Comment: remove async and defer and then try if it works then its probably your maps are not loading even after view is ready.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`agm/core` loads google maps & sets your api key within the module import, so you do not need `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&libraries=places" async defer></script>`

Follow their getting started [tutorial](https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/). You'll end up with something like

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get key from google maps and then place that key in app.module.ts under `@NgModule`

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
   apiKey: 'your key generated from google maps'
});
```

and in HTML add this

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
   <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

and also this in the CSS

```
agm-map {
  height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need just add corresponding dependencies and types to your project.
So these are.

in tsconfig.json -> `"types":[... "googlemaps"]`

in package.json -> `"dependencies":[...  "googlemaps": "^1.12.0"]`

And don't forget about the API key which you should get from https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key, after having it you set it to the module via `AgmCoreModule` or just adding import script into HTML, I am using GMap component of `PrimeNG` and all these steps helped me go forward.